# When using OpenVPN, TAP-Windows Adapter V9 says its unplugged after a few months

Tags: openvpn

After a few months of using OpenVPN inside a Windows virtual machine, the TAP adapter stops working and says it's unplugged.

I have no idea how to fix this. Seems like something needs to be cleared or reset? I don't know if its something on the virtual machine that needs to be reset or something on the parent machine (also running windows 10).

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Network cable unplugged just means that it can't connect. It is a symptom of the problem and not the problem itself.

In my case, there was an issue on the server with it timing out the certificate on the client after a few months.